# Difference between column type "termColumn" and "multiterm" SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I was checking the official Microsoft Graph Documentation about working with columns in SharePoint because I found two types of properties that have similar type names, but I am not sure if they are the same or not.

On one of my SharePoint lists I've created a "Managed metadata" column manually. I wanted to see the type of this column. I've used the next HTTP call:

GET sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/columns

And I've noticed that the type of this column is "multiterm". On the official Microsoft Graph Documentation they don't mention this type but they mention the type "termColumn", and I don't know if they are the same type or not.

Here is the link to the list of types [columnDefinition resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/columndefinition?view=graph-rest-1.0)

So if anyone has a clue about this please tell me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TermColumn:

A "termColumn" is a column type that allows you to associate a single term from a term set with an item in a list or library. This is used for creating a single-value column that can be linked to a term from your organization's term store. TermColumns are often used for categorizing and classifying content in a consistent manner.

Characteristics:

Single-value column: You can associate only one term from the term set with each item.
Typically used for scenarios where a single classification or categorization is sufficient.
Useful for ensuring consistency in metadata across items.
Provides options for creating relationships between terms, enabling hierarchical categorization.
Managed metadata navigation can be configured using term columns.
MultiTerm:

"MultiTerm" refers to the ability to associate multiple terms from a term set with an item using a column. In other words, a "multiterm" column allows you to link an item to more than one term within a term set. This provides greater flexibility in classifying content and capturing multiple aspects of metadata.

Characteristics:

Multi-value column: You can associate multiple terms from the term set with each item.
Useful for scenarios where items need to be classified with multiple terms simultaneously.
Enables more detailed and complex categorization.
Provides the ability to capture various facets of metadata within a single column.
Particularly beneficial when dealing with items that have multiple dimensions or attributes.